# Combining multiple IF formulas

Tags: excel

How can I combine these two formulas, so that it looks for BOB or JOE and enters the correct answer or if neither it should just enter `-`?

```
=IF(R15="BOB","YES","-")
=IF(R15="JOE","NO","-")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the second in the False return of the first:

```
=IF(R15="BOB","YES",IF(R15="JOE","NO","-"))
```

Comment: Thank You that's it